# число элементов базы данных MNIST

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, tensorflow

Никак не могу понять, каким образом можно посчитать количество тренировочных и тестируемых изображений базы данных рукописных цифр при помощи tensorflow.
Пробовал так:

```
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
print(tf.keras.datasets.mnist.train_images.num_examples)
```

Выдает ошибку работы с атрибутами.

Answer (score 0):

MNIST содержит 60000 тренировочных и 10000 тестовых изображений ([MNIST](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/)), а в коде это можно получить:

```
len(train_images) # 60000
len(test_images) # 10000
```